# Making video in Iframe responsive

Tags: php, html, iframe

I have a Wordpress-site in which I have placed an Iframe. In this Iframe I'm streaming video. This is all well and good, but when I try the website on my Iphone (not android) the iframe has a huuuuge width. I tried:

```
width: auto;
```

This doesn't produce any results.

The website is http://www.bubbels-lelystad.nl/broadcast-live/ and the code I use is:

```
< iframe src="http://client.branchechannel.com/?id=0ff39bbbf981ac0151d340c9aa40e63e" frameborder="0" style="border: 0; width: 1100px; height: 600px;"></iframe>
```

Comment: Basically you can't make the content in an IFrame responsive. The people who coded the video will need to implement the responsive framework. You can make the IFrame it self responsive, but you can't change the code within unless you plan on using Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class = "video-container">
<iframe src="http://client.branchechannel.com/?id=0ff39bbbf981ac0151d340c9aa40e63e" height="600px" width="1100px" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0">
</iframe>
</div>
```

iframe is one of the html elements that does not play nice with responsive layouts. The best way for embedded content is to make a wrapper around it.

this is the css: *You can tweak it to your liking but it seems to adapt to different screen size*

```
.video-container {
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 56.25%;
padding-top: 35px;
height: 0;
overflow: hidden;
}

.video-container iframe {
position: absolute;
top:0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

padding-bottom/top you can tweak to your liking. That is based on the aspect-ratio of the video.